# I need to use iOS face detection to detect faces from live video, then crop each face into an array of faces

Tags: ios, swift, face-detection

I have the face detection working, and can add a red rectangle around each face at a timed interval. The problem I cannot get past is cropping each detected face into an array of face images. I know the coordinate system is reversed for the detected faces and the cropping part, but cant figure out how to get the faces to crop correctly. How do I crop each face from the faces result from the original "capturedImage"..?

```
  let image = CIImage.init(cvPixelBuffer: capturedImage)
    //imgFull.image = UIImage(ciImage: image.oriented(CGImagePropertyOrientation.right).cropped(to: CGRect.init(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 200)));


    let imageOptions =  NSDictionary(object: NSNumber(value: 8) as NSNumber, forKey: CIDetectorImageOrientation as NSString)

    let options = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
    let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: options)!
    let faces = faceDetector.features(in: image, options: imageOptions as? [String : AnyObject])


    let detectFaceRequest = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest { (request, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            //Loop through the resulting faces and add a red UIView on top of them.
            if let faces = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] {
                for face in faces {

                    let faceView = UIView(frame: self.faceFrame(from: face.boundingBox))

                    let newImage: CGImage = self.convertCIImageToCGImage(inputImage: image.oriented(CGImagePropertyOrientation.right))

                    let imageRef: CGImage = (newImage.cropping(to: face.boundingBox))!
                    let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
                    self.imgFull.image = croppedImage;
```

Comment: This function is doing way too much. You would have a much easier time if you broke it down into parts. One function to detect the faces, another to crop images from them.

Comment: what about you give it a look: https://medium.com/@kravik/ios-11-tutorial-vision-framework-3c836d5ecadd